# Marketing Cloud iOS SDK inbox message read status does not change after opening message from push notification

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios

I have an issue with Marketing Cloud iOS SDK. I have implemented Inbox feature and showing some internal unread messages count badges. I'm manually marking inbox messages as read using SDK method. The question is how to mark message opened from push notification (push+inbox) as read? I only have a message url and type (using MarketingCloudSDKURLHandlingDelegate) and filtering message would not be so accurate. Or maybe SDK handles this case out of the box, but I don't know how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, you can look at the `_m` value in the push notification's userInfo payload (the push message ID) and compare it to the `messageId` value of the inbox message dictionary (from `sfmc_getAllMessages`, for instance).

Then, you can use `sfmc_markMessageRead` to set that message to read in the SDK.